# ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier always return null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

actually am new in asp.net core 3.1 , i am trying to create user login and register with cookies
when i am try to get `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` always return null, can you help me please ?
controller code

```
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApiSiteDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<AppRole> _roleManager;

        public AccountController(ApiSiteDbContext db,
            UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager,
            RoleManager<AppRole> roleManager)
        {
            _db = db;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel loginModel)
        {                
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginModel.Email);
                          
           // **** this is always return null ***** 
            var id = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
            if (id != null)
            {
                return BadRequest("User already logged !!");
            }

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginModel.Password, loginModel.RememberMe, true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User"))
                {
                    if (!await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "User"))
                    {
                        await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
                    }
                }

                var roleName = await GetRoleNameByUserId(user.Id);
                if (roleName != null)
                {
                    AddCookies(user.UserName, user.Id, roleName,  loginModel.RememberMe, user.Email);
                }
                return Ok();
            }
            else if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return Unauthorized("Your account were locked");
            }
            return BadRequest("Wrong  password!");
            //return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);
        }

        public async void AddCookies(string userName, string userId, string roleName, bool remember, string email)
        {
            var claim = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName),
            };

            var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claim, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            if (remember)
            {
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    IsPersistent = true,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10)
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync
                    (
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity),
                        authProperties
                    );
            }
            else
            {
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    AllowRefresh = true,
                    IsPersistent = false,
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)
                };

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync
                    (
                        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity),
                        authProperties
                    );
            }
        }
    }
```

and in Startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = Context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
            services.AddControllers();
            //services.AddControllersWithViews();
           
            services.AddDbContext<ApiSiteDbContext>();
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(option =>
            {
                option.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                option.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                option.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;
                option.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                option.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                option.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                option.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                option.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                option.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiSiteDbContext>()
          .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.LogoutPath = "/api/Account/Logout";
                //options.LoginPath = "/api/Account/Login";
                //options.AccessDeniedPath = "/api/Account/accessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });


            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
              .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

            services.AddCors();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
            app.UseMvc();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

when i make this variable to check the NameIdentifier if return id or not before i use it in a different controller .

Comment: In your `Login` method, if `id` != `null`, you return `BadRequest`. That means when you eventually call your `AddCookies` method (where you add the `NameIdentifier` claim), `id` is guaranteed to be `null` at that point. That would be why it's always `null`, right?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @crgolden it's not must return every time with null ,i make this variable to ensure that's return with value but it didn't , it must be in first login null and if user is logged return bad request with a message i put it to test

Comment: @MohamedElSoufi  when you first login make sure `AddCookies` method called, otherwise it will not have `NameIdentifier ` claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the roleName variable is not a null or string empty, because adding cookies depends on this condition